# How to use url_for to generate a path that doesn't exist in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

This might not be possible, but I thought I'd ask. I need to generate paths that are not present in my routes file.

For example I would like to be able to generate:

```rb
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
url_for(
  {
    :controller => 'accounts',
    :action     => 'index',
    :id         => '123',
    :only_path  => true
  }
) # => "/accounts?id=123"
```

The above will raise a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches`.

Comment: show your `rails routes` output pls

Comment: You can pass extra params in your routes, just don't call it id. For example the following route will go to index action, if you have `ressources accounts` : `accounts_path(other_id: '123')` => /accounts?other_id='123' (I am not in front of my computer to check typos but you understand the point :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that AFAIK. url_for infers a lot of thing from the routes map and the url generated wouldn't work anyway.

What's the use case ? Maybe there's a better solution available.